# Pseudo R^2 using VGLM

Tags: r

I have been asked to provide a pseudo R2 value for a regression I am running in R.  I am using the  vglm command to run the regression on a 4-category patient quality of life number given the patient pulmonary arterial strain, pulse pressure and maximum pulmonary arterial pressure.

However, vglm only provides the Residual Deviance and does not provide the Null Deviance.  The pseudo-R2, goodness-of-fit measurements that I have looked up from previous posts all require the null deviance.  Is there a way to get or calculate the null deviance from vglm?
https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~yee/VGAM/doc/VGAMrefcard.pdf

Thanks,
Shawna

```
> summary(fit)

Call:
vglm(formula = resp_var ~ Strain + PP + Pmax, family = multinomial, data = DF)

Pearson Residuals:
                   Min       1Q    Median        3Q    Max
log(mu[,1]/mu[,4]) -3.8849 -0.45457  0.237302  0.456967 4.9936
log(mu[,2]/mu[,4]) -2.7173 -0.45528 -0.255479  0.601062 2.1737
log(mu[,3]/mu[,4]) -2.7175 -0.15174 -0.096334 -0.041271 6.6040

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error    z value
(Intercept):1 -18.37926   1609.958 -0.0114160
(Intercept):2 -22.19514   1609.958 -0.0137862
(Intercept):3 -24.72028   1609.958 -0.0153546
Strain:1      286.66750   3989.303  0.0718590
Strain:2      285.95551   3989.303  0.0716806
Strain:3      284.37742   3989.303  0.0712850
PP:1           -0.87220     67.951 -0.0128356
PP:2           -0.77133     67.951 -0.0113512
PP:3           -0.93263     67.951 -0.0137250
Pmax:1          0.15845     28.841  0.0054941
Pmax:2          0.17548     28.841  0.0060843
Pmax:3          0.28930     28.841  0.0100307

Number of linear predictors:  3 

Names of linear predictors: 
log(mu[,1]/mu[,4]), log(mu[,2]/mu[,4]), log(mu[,3]/mu[,4])

Dispersion Parameter for multinomial family:   1

Residual deviance: 102.8416 on 222 degrees of freedom

Log-likelihood: -51.42081 on 222 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations: 19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null deviance is the residual deviance of a null (intercept-only) model, e.g. `resp_var ~ 1`. So to calculate McFadden's pseudo-R-squared:

```
# generate sample data
set.seed(101)
resp_var = t(rmultinom(100, 1, rep(0.25, 4)))
DF = data.frame(Strain = rnorm(100), PP = rnorm(100), Pmax = rnorm(100))

# fit models
m1 <- vglm(formula = resp_var ~ Strain + PP + Pmax, family = multinomial, data = DF)
null <- vglm(formula = resp_var ~ 1, family = multinomial, data = DF)

# McFadden's pseudo-R^2
print(pseudo_R2 <- 1 - deviance(m1) / deviance(null))

# [1] 0.05300655
```

This agrees, for example, with `mlogit`:

```
library(mlogit)
DF$cat_resp = factor(apply(resp_var, 1, function(.) which(. == 1) ) )
mDf <- mlogit.data(DF, choice = "cat_resp", shape = "wide")
summary(mlogit(cat_resp ~ 1|Strain + PP + Pmax, data = mDf))

# Call:
# mlogit(formula = cat_resp ~ 1 | Strain + PP + Pmax, data = mDf, 
#    method = "nr", print.level = 0)
# ...
# ...
# Log-Likelihood: -130.03
# McFadden R^2:  0.053007 
# Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 14.557 (p.value = 0.10386)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and for the mlogit code, I really appreciate the help!